# Duplicating memory layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, memory, copy

I kept my original question clear and concise to make it easier to answer.  This is a response to requests for more information.

**Introduction**
I am using QGIS version 2.18.9. I created about 20 new memory layers by clicking on "Layer", then "Create Layer", then "New Memory Layer".  I want to create 8 duplicates of each layer.

**Aim**
I want to avoid creating from scratch multiple layers containing identically-shaped polygons.  I want to create duplicates so I can simply change the colour of each polygon to represent different data.

**Problems**
When I right click on a layer and then click "Duplicate" I get an error message saying "Memory Layer type unsupported"

**What I have tried**
As above.  I have not found anything else on the program that looks promising.  I have not found any topics on here that help.  My knowledge is limited and I am not familiar with all the jargon or protocols.

Comment: which QGIS version are you using what type is your layer? please give more context

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: 1) an introduction to your problem, 2) What you hope to accomplish, 3) and error messages or problems encountered, and 4) What you may have tried.

Comment: Can you provide more information like a screenshot of your problem? So, would it maybe make sense to save your memory layer as a shapefile and then duplicate it? If you want to avoid to begin from scratch again, not working with memory-layers could be a first step.

Comment: What kind of datasets make up  your layer(s)?.  If you open up Windows Explorer and browse to a shapefile, you can drag the shp into your project window 8 times pretty quickly and then work on each layer's color.  You could use the add data button 8 times each for any data type too but that is probably what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: "Duplicate" no longer shows as an option when I right click on a layer, so I cannot show a screen shot of that.   I get the same result from choosing "Duplicate" from the "Layers" tab (.i.e. " ! Duplicate layer... Memory Layer type unsupported") but I can't seem to paste a screen shot here.  If I right click on the memory layer and choose save as I can save it as a shapefile and can duplicate that.  Thanks Dirk

Answer (score 2):

- Using **PyQGIS**, you can create another memory layer and copy the features over:

  ```
  layer = iface.activeLayer()
  feats = [feat for feat in layer.getFeatures()]
  # Use "Polygon" for polygon layer; "Point" for point layer; "LineString" for line layer
  mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "duplicated_layer", "memory")

  mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
  attr = layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
  mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
  mem_layer.updateFields()
  mem_layer_data.addFeatures(feats)

  QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
  ```
- The **Speedy Layer** plugin also allows you to select a loaded layer (including memory layers) and output another memory layer. You can also select the features and fields you want copied over. You can download/install this from the menubar:

  ```
  Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...
  ```

  [image: Speedy Layer Interface]

Comment: Thanks but pyQGIS looks too complicated for me and I have downloaded Speedy Layer but don't know what to do next.  I was hoping for a simple answer.

Comment: @user34581 - For the Speedy Layer plugin, you select a layer you want to duplicate from the `Choose Layer` list, then leave the `Only selected features` option unchecked and don't select any fields. Then click `Speed Up` to create the duplicated layer :)